# Does back to back connection of PN diode works exactly as transistor?

Tags: diodes

I have a doubt related to back to back connection of PN diode....

**Does [back to back connection of PN diode works](http://www.electronicshub.org/introduction-to-transistors/) exactly as transistor?**

It looks like a small doubt... But I want detailed information about it. So, can anybody explain about it in detailed manner?

Comment: The English of that article isn't very well written. It doesn't look like a good learning resource.

Comment: Depending on how deep you are studying BJTs just think of the carriers distribution: the profile in the base can be something meaningful only if the base lenght is comparable to the diffusion length, that's in the 10um ballpark. When you connect two diodes back to back the base is some mm long at least, so you have a transistor but with very, very, very poor performances.

Comment: I don't think it's fair you're being downvoted; you read an article, you were curious about a concept, and asked it clearly. English isn't your first language so how are you supposed to know that it is not a good resource?

Answer (score 4):

No. A BJT shares one of the regions with *both* junctions, plus the regions in a BJT are asymmetrical in both size *and* doping strength. Both of these factors contribute to the fact that BJTs act as current amplification devices rather than just pairs of rectification devices.